# Getting difficulties in JPA/Hibernate @OneToMany List(with @OrderColumn) mapping by @JoinTable

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am new in JPA & I am following "Java Persistence With Hibernate 2nd Edition" book to learn. I am getting some difficulties in @OneToMany bidirectional List(with @OrderColumn) mapping by @JoinTable. I didn't face any issue with @JoinColumn, but seems I am doing something wrong in case of @JoinTable. I've given my example below.

ADDRESS CLASS:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ADDRESS")
public class Address {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "MY_ID_GENERATOR")
    @Column(name="_ADDRESS_ID")
    private Long addressId;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="_CITY", nullable = false)
    protected String city;

    //-------------------------------------
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinTable(
        name = "ADDRESS_LIST",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "_A_ID", unique = true, updatable = false, insertable = false, referencedColumnName = "_ADDRESS_ID")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "_P_ID", updatable = false, insertable = false, referencedColumnName = "_PERSON_ID")}
    )
    private Person person;
    //-------------------------------------

    protected Address() {}
    public Address(@NotNull String city) {
        super();
        this.city = city;
    }
    public Address(@NotNull String city, Person person) {
        super();
        this.city = city;
        this.person = person;
    }
    public Long getId() { return addressId; }
    public String getCity() { return city; }
    public void setCity(String city) { this.city = city; }
    public Person getPerson() { return person; }
    public void setPerson(Person person) { this.person = person; }
}
```

PERSON CLASS:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "MY_ID_GENERATOR")
    @Column(name="_PERSON_ID")
    private Long personId;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="_NAME", nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String name;

    //-------------------------------------
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinTable(
        name = "ADDRESS_LIST",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "_P_ID", referencedColumnName = "_PERSON_ID")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "_A_ID", unique = true, referencedColumnName = "_ADDRESS_ID")}
    )
    @OrderColumn(name = "_ORDER", nullable = false)
    private List<Address> addressList = new ArrayList<>();
    //-------------------------------------

    public Person() {
        super();
    }
    public Person(@NotNull String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Long getPersonId() { return personId; }
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
    public List<Address> getAddressList() { return addressList; }
    public void setAddressList(List<Address> addressList) { this.addressList = addressList; }
}
```

Now in main class if I take care of both side association, it is not working!!

```
Person person = new Person("Sourangshu Biswas");
person.getAddressList().add(new Address("Siliguri", person));
person.getAddressList().add(new Address("Kolkata", person));
person.getAddressList().add(new Address("Chennai", person));
```

Giving error!!

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Field '_P_ID' doesn't have a default value.
```

But if I don't pass the "person" object in the "Address()" constrictor, It is working.

```
Person person = new Person("Sourangshu Biswas");
person.getAddressList().add(new Address("Siliguri"));
person.getAddressList().add(new Address("Kolkata"));
person.getAddressList().add(new Address("Chennai"));
```

I've checked the DB, I am getting values in the "_ORDER" column also!! But by question is how this is working!! As per my knowledge, We have to taken care of both side in bidirectional association. Why it is not working when I am passing the "person" object in the "Address()" constrictor!!!!?? The "person" object not yet persisted, that's why? But same kind of thing I've done in other types(SET/BAG) of mapping, that time it worked.

Comment: Forgot to mention, I am persisting "person" object by: em.persist(person);

Comment: (1) Add `mappedBy="person"`, to `@OneToMany`, (2) remove the `@JoinTable` from `Person.addressList`, (3) remove `updatable = false, insertable = false` from the join column declarations in the remaining `@JoinTable`

Comment: @crizzis Thanks for your reply but I have a doubt whether mappedBy="person" at OneToMany side will work here or not!!? NOTE: It is a bidirectional LIST mapping and I want to use OrderColumn as well. According to the "Java Persistence With Hibernate 2nd Edition" book (Page: 185), this case is an exception.

Answer (score 0):

> NOTE: It is a bidirectional LIST mapping and I want to use OrderColumn as well. According to the "Java Persistence With Hibernate 2nd Edition" book (Page: 185), this case is an exception.

What the book mentions is a workaround for creating an ordered bidirectional one-to-many association **using a join column**, which is very different. Here, you've in fact created two separate associations that happen to use the same join table. Now:

> if I don't pass the "person" object in the "Address()" constrictor, It is working.

When `Address.person` is set to `null`, Hibernate does not try to persist the many-to-one association. Hence, a single `INSERT` statement gets generated (storing the one-to-many association only):

```
INSERT INTO ADDRESS_LIST(_P_ID, _A_ID) VALUES (?, ?);
```

> in main class if I take care of both side association, it is not working!!

If you add the `Address` into `Person.addressList` *and* assign a non-null `Person` to `Address.person`, Hibernate will try to persist both associations. Two `INSERT` statements will be generated: one for the one-to-many association (similar to the one above), and another one for the many-to-one association - something like:

```
INSERT INTO ADDRESS_LIST() VALUES ();
```

Why the empty column list and the empty value list? **Because you've marked both join columns of the join table `insertable=false`**. The database complains that a value for the `_P_ID` column is missing - and understandably so, since `_P_ID` cannot be `NULL`, and there's no default value to use.

Of course, if you drop the `insertable=false`, both `INSERT` statements will be identical, resulting in either a constraint violation, or a duplicate row in `ADDRESS_LIST`.

Long story short: you're not supposed to 'take care of both sides of the association', because this is not a bidirectional association - these are in fact two completely separate ones.

Note that for a workaround similar to the join column approach to work, **you would need to mark the entire many-to-one's `@JoinTable` as `insertable=false`, not just the individual join columns** - something JPA has no support for.

Comment: Thank you @crizzis for giving your valuable time. This is exactly the same thing which I tried to make but faced complexity.   https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/jpa/one-to-many-bidirectional-join-table.html

Comment: In the mean time I am also trying to understand whatever you have said. Thanks :-)